# AspxGridView and ShowHeaderFilterButton property

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

my question is very simple. I have an AspxGridView with a DataTable as datasource.
Whene i filter rows by using the combox enabled by the ShowHeaderFilterButton property, the datasource is not updated and my row count remain the same.

How can i count the rows not hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASPxGridView does not apply a filter condition on the underlying DataSource.  So, after the filtering is done, the grid's DataSource has the same record count as it had before.  A possible solution to this problem is to traverse through gridRows and getting required KeyField values or Row objects:

```
object[] rows = new object[ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++) {
            rows[i] = ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(i, ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName);
            //or
            rows[i] = ASPxGridView1.GetRow(i);
        }
```